# Generating Colors between two colors javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a map theme in which users can select two colors based on user input the theme is made consisting of colors between those two input colors, any ideas how can i get colors between two input colors.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the RGB values from hex code of colors and then you can use it to find the intermediate color. Eg. Consider 2 colors `#DCE7FA` and `#CADBF7`

```
r1 = DC ; r2 = CA  
g1 = E7 ; g2 = DB  
b1 = FA ; b2 = F7
```

using individual medians..

```
r3 = (r1+r2)/2 = D3 ;  
g3 = E1  
b3 = F5
```

now your intermediate color = `#D3E1F5`

Comment: that's the method/approach for finding a color between two colors (intermediate color)

Comment: i want many colors nearly about 20 to 30 between two specific colors??

Comment: then you can repeat the same process desired number of times. Eg. find a color between two given colors. Now you have 3 colors say A,B,C Repeat the process to find colors betwee A-B and B-C. You'll now have 5 colors A,D,B,E,C At `nth` step you will have `(n*2)-1` colors so for 20 colors `(n*2)-1=20` => `n=10.5 or 11` since number of steps should be int.